# Select rows having equal values in one column but not those are alone

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my SQLfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a335/1/0

[image]

The result I want is the same like picture but without the 2 red rows, because for id_association_mots_idM 476 and 478, there is no traduction in english in the table.

I tried many requests and many ways.
Is it possible and if yes, how ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're really going to have to start formatting and indenting your SQLs nicely if you want them to be maintainable in future

The following query excludes the red rows:

```
SELECT 
  ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM, 
  ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM, 
  v_a_m.categorie_v , 
  v_a_m.mot_v 

FROM 
`association_mots_id_mot` AS ass_m_m
INNER JOIN
`association_mots_login` AS ass_m_l
ON 
  ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM = ass_m_l.id_association_mots AND 
  ass_m_l.id_login_mL = '1'

INNER JOIN 
`vocabulaire_a_memoriser` AS v_a_m 
ON
  ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM = v_a_m.id_vocab AND 
  (v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_francais' OR v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_anglais')

INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM 
  FROM 
    `association_mots_id_mot` AS ass_m_m
    INNER JOIN 
    `vocabulaire_a_memoriser` AS v_a_m 
    ON
      ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM = v_a_m.id_vocab AND 
      (v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_francais' OR v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_anglais')
   GROUP BY
     ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM
   HAVING COUNT(distinct categorie_v) = 2  
) wanted
ON
  ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM = wanted.id_association_mots_idM
```

I've converted the query to ANSI join syntax - please avoid using the old `SELECT * FROM a,b,c,d WHERE a.id=b.id ...` syntax

The top part of your query is your query (converted join syntax, and laid out indented so we have a chance of seeing what's going on) unchanged

The bit that does the work is this subquery:

```
(
  SELECT 
    ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM 
  FROM 
    `association_mots_id_mot` AS ass_m_m
    INNER JOIN 
    `vocabulaire_a_memoriser` AS v_a_m 
    ON
      ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM = v_a_m.id_vocab AND 
      (v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_francais' OR v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_anglais')
   GROUP BY
     ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM
   HAVING COUNT(distinct categorie_v) = 2  
) wanted
```

It reduces the `ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM` list of `2,2,5,5,5,476,478` to just `2,5` because they are the only `ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM` that have a `COUNT(DISTINCT language)` of 2 - i.e. they're the only rows where 2 distinct language values appear

Then, because the output of this query is just `2,5` when it's joined into the main, it restricts the main query to just rows where the iass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM is 2 or 5

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly ! I forgot to indent my SQL request sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id_association_mots_idm = t.id_association_mots_idm and
                    t2.category_v = 'langue_anglais'
             );
```

Comment: @Jean . . . You should put the link in for the SQL Fiddle.  There is nothing obviously wrong with the code, and this is likely the simplest answer to your question.

Comment: The output of SQLfiddle is "Table 'db_9_6a335.t' doesn't exist"

Comment: @Jean . . . `t` is the table that contains your data.   Further, I have no idea what the SQL Fiddle has to do with the question, because the columns are different.  You need to adjust the table and column names for your data.  I can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

The query below excludes the RED rows.

```
SELECT v_all.id_association_mots_idM,
       v_all.id_vocab_idM,
       v_all.id_vocab_idM,
       v_all.mot_v
  FROM (SELECT  ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM, 
                ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM, 
                v_a_m.categorie_v , 
                v_a_m.mot_v 
        FROM  `association_mots_login` AS ass_m_l,  
              `association_mots_id_mot` AS ass_m_m, 
              `vocabulaire_a_memoriser` AS v_a_m 
        WHERE ass_m_l.id_association_mots  = ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM
          AND ass_m_l.id_login_mL = '1'
          AND ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM = v_a_m.id_vocab 
          AND v_a_m.categorie_v IN ('langue_francais', 'langue_anglais')) v_all,
        (SELECT DISTINCT ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM
          FROM  `association_mots_login` AS ass_m_l,  
                `association_mots_id_mot` AS ass_m_m, 
                `vocabulaire_a_memoriser` AS v_a_m 
          WHERE ass_m_l.id_association_mots  = ass_m_m.id_association_mots_idM
            AND ass_m_l.id_login_mL = '1'
            AND ass_m_m.id_vocab_idM = v_a_m.id_vocab 
            AND v_a_m.categorie_v = 'langue_anglais') v_eng 
WHERE v_all.id_association_mots_idM = v_eng.id_association_mots_idM        ;
```

**Explanation:**

In-line view v_all is same as what you had. Gets all the records for both langue_francais and langue_anglais. Inline view v_eng only gets the records where there is a traduction in english i.e. langue_anglais. 
Inner joining the 2 views would give you just the records with english traduction.

Hope this helps!